# convert list to vector when use for loop in R

Tags: r

How can I convert  list to vector in R here?

```
a1 <- matrix(rcauchy(10*200, 0, 1), 200)

for (i in 1:150) {
  if (shapiro.test(a1[i,])$p.value >= 0.05) {
    print(t.test(a1[i,], alternative = "two.sided")$p.value)
  }
}
```

I use this code but I get only the first value

```
p <- NULL
for (i in 1:150) {
  p[i] <- if (shapiro.test(a1[i,])$p.value>=0.05) {
    (t.test(a1[i,], alternative = "two.sided")$p.value)
  }
}
p
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the code run without errors, you just need to have an `else` statement for when the condition is false

```
p <- NULL
for (i in 1:150) {
  p[i] <- if (shapiro.test(a1[i, ])$p.value >= 0.05) {
    (t.test(a1[i, ], alternative = "two.sided")$p.value)
  } else {
    NA
  }
  print(i)
}
p
```

Comment: It's also better to create the output vector beforehand, `p<-numeric(150)`.

Answer (score 1):

A `apply` loop solution.

```r
a1 <- matrix(rcauchy(10*200, 0, 1), 200)

p <- apply(a1, 1, \(a){
  if(shapiro.test(a)$p.value >= 0.05)
    t.test(a)$p.value
  else NA_real_
})
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>